# JApplet to get data from other webpage

Tags: java, security, url, japplet, accesscontrolexception

I made a currency converter that gets the latest currency rates from yahoo.
As long as I run it from the applet viewer it works fine, I can convert any currencies. When I open the html file the applet works but I can't convert any currencies and I can't retrieve any rates.

```
        Url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EURUSD%3DX&ql=1";

        URLPage = new URL(Cur);
        Input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(URLPage.openStream()));
        while ((inputLine = Input.readLine()) != null) {
          results = results + inputLine;
        }

        Input.close();
        Pattern patternSeeked = Pattern.compile("x\">([0-9.]+)</span>");
        Matcher findMatch = patternSeeked.matcher(results);
        findMatch.find();
```

The exception I get is java.security.AccessCOntrolException: access denied("java.net.SocketPermission" "finance.yahoo.com:80" "connect,resolve");

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: No, none. I added a try-catch exception in case it wouldn't connect to yahoo but it's never called.

Comment: Actually it throws a RuntimeException...

Comment: Post that stacktrace please. And the relevant lines of code it's referring to.

Comment: Only a trusted applet can reach across domains.  Is Yahoo permitting you to reuse their data?

Comment: No, I don't think it is. How do I do it?